# Easy way to upload photos to Blogger blog directly from Bibble?

Tags: blog, bibble

I have a Google Blogger [blog](http://blog.reidster.net) that I use to share photos with family & friends. I also use Bibble Lite 5.1 to process my photos. I'm on Linux (Debian Lenny, 32-bit to be specific).

Here's my current workflow:

1. Edit images.
2. Send images to a batch output queue, creating JPEGs.
3. Go to Blogger and create a new post.
4. Click the "add images" button.
5. Navigate to the new JPEGs and upload them.
6. The Blogger new post window with the images in it is ready for typing.

Here's my desired workflow (very similar to how Picasa works):

1. Edit images.
2. Send images to some batch output queue.
3. A Blogger new post window appears with the images in it, ready for typing.

Is it possible to get this desired workflow, and if so how?

Bibble has the ability to call an arbitrary program with arbitrary arguments after outputting a JPEG, so that's a potential hook to use.

Comment: One solution seems to be the answer to the question "which blogger clients will take images as arguments?" [A: I have no idea.] You might try this one on SuperUser, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a glue script which implements almost all of my desired workflow. The only missing part is that I have to bring up the Blogger draft post manually, but that's no big deal.

The script is listed on my [software page](http://reidster.net/software/) as "bibbleblog" and here's the [direct link](http://reidster.net/software/bibbleblog). Feel free to modify and redistribute (BSD 3-clause license).

It's a Python program of about 250 lines including installation and use instructions. It runs on Linux and probably other UNIX-like systems, perhaps Mac OS X.

*Thanks to Karel for pointing out this was possible. I made this the accepted answer because it's more comprehensive, but it wouldn't have happened without him.*

Answer (score 4):

One idea: it should be possible to send images to Blogger with email, now the question remains if Bibble supports email output (ie Picasa does).

Comment: I use Picasa and email to post to blogger.

Comment: Thanks, this looks very promising. It will require some glue scripting (since there's one app call per image, but I want to upload them all in a batch), but that won't be too hard.

Comment: This is going to work. I'll post my script in a new answer when I get to it, as a significant amount of voodoo is required.

Comment: Good to hear that my answer was helpful :)